# Implications for using unsafe in a .NET library

Tags: c#, iis, cas, unsafe

I'm considering optimizing certain areas in my library (Npgsql, PostgreSQL driver for .NET) with unsafe operations.

Now, it's clearly stated in various places (e.g. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474(v=vs.71).aspx)) that unsafe code is only executed in a full trust environment. I'm wondering what exactly this means in 2016, for a library that aims to be usable in a as many contexts as possible - does IIS permit libraries with unsafe code? Are there other environments which don't allow them? CAS and medium trust seem to be deprecated, and in general it's difficult to get a clear picture of the current situation.